# How to configure proxy in debian with alfresco "Configuring SSL"

Tags: proxy, alfresco

I can't edit online MS Office documents. When I click on "Edit online" for excel/word file Excel/Word application starts but I have message ERROR for that I have to do some configuration look in this tutorial  http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/configure-ssl-prod.html but I don t know how to set a proxy in my environment My environment is debian  TurnKey GNU/Linux 15.0 / TurnKey 9.4 Stretch[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZLi6.png)

Comment: could you please post your error too? what version of alfresco are you using?

Comment: My version of alfresco is : 5.2 . I want simply set the proxy in debian with configuration SSL but I don't know how . the error is a pop up window "we are sorry but it is impossible to open word 127.0.0.1 ....."